# Digitized points are getting displaced automatically in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

We are capturing 100's of drilling sample locations in QGIS. At times, we are copying the whole set of points from adjacent survey_lines to the next one. After that, we will capture the respective mineral values. But once we save it and open the shapefile again, the points are getting displaced randomly (but not all the points), just like in the image.

Actual values are 110,20,15,20,30 etc... But the respective points are displaced to some other place and had been replaced by some other points. One can see captured values (yellow) doesn't match with the actual values (black). Will it be a bug or due to any plugins or due to copying - pasting of points or any other thing?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what points are displaced, can you highlight them in the image?

Comment: I've edited the question. Could you take an another look ?

Comment: Are your source and paste layers in exactly the same CRS?

Comment: Yes. I've copied only the adjacent points within the same layer.

Comment: So the problem lays on the values, not the position of points? How do you "capture the respective mineral values"?

Comment: Following Simbamangu ideia, Is layer CRS and project CRS the same?

Comment: Once i've digitized all the points, i've generated X & Y coordinates. And then i've captured either individually or using Multiattribute plugin. When i found out this problem, i've saved it as CSV and i've plotted the points using the X & Y columns and all the points sits perfectly at their respective places with correct values. I reckon, the problem is not with the values. Yes, layer CRS and Project CRS are same